# Using cond in mongo aggregate match expression

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So i'm trying to query products based on the user specified filter. if the user specifies the size, for example XS, then i fetch all the products with 'XS' sizes, otherwise if the size isn't specified then i will fetch all the products without checking for their size. How can i do it with the mongo aggregation ?

here's my code.
1st:  here's 2 products documents from my collection

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6124d16b1396d20aea617d75",
        "username": "josh988",
        "userpic": "josh.jpg",
        "adresse": "545 Strawberry Lane Mokena, IL 60448",
        "city": "Paris",
        "country": "France",
        "product": {
            "_id": "62c064103a7b5160e957764c",
            "images": [
                "img1734116er1111111.jpeg"
            ],
            "name": "White shirt",
            "category": "Kids",
            "subCategory": "Tshirts",
            "size": "XS",
            "price": 150
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "6124d16b1396d20aea617d75",
        "username": "laurel22",
        "userpic": "laurel.jpg",
        "adresse": "545 Strawberry Lane Mokena, IL 60448",
        "city": "Lyon",
        "country": "France",
        "product": {
            "_id": "62c064103a7b5160e957764c",
            "images": [
                "img1711656775696063.jpeg"
            ],
            "name": "Black shirt",
            "category": "Kids",
            "subCategory": "Tshirts",
            "size": "M",
            "price": 250
        }
    },
]
```

to make the matter simple , my body api body request looks like this

```
{  
   "selectedCategory": "Kids",
   "selectedSubCategory": "Tshirts",
    // for e.g selectedSize could be XS 
   "selectedSize": null 
   
}
```

So what i'd like to do is, if the user select a size then fetch the products with it otherwise fetch everything.

I tried this with mongo but didn't work

```
const searchResults = await user.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          "product.category": `${req.body.selectedCategory}`,
          "product.subCategory": `${req.body.selectedSubCategory}`,
          $expr: {
            $cond: {
              // what should i do here ? or is there another way of achieving this 
              if: { $ne: [`${req.body.selectedSize}`, null] },
              then: { product.size : req.body.selectedSize },
              // and what should write here to fetch everything 
              else: { product.size: "" },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Comment: It is simpler to have _two_ statement, one with `product.size` specified and one without. Depending on whether `req.body.selectedSize` is present, the one is executed or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the aggregation pipeline conditionally in `nodejs` itself. Like this:

```
let matchStage = {
        $match: {
          "product.category": `${req.body.selectedCategory}`,
          "product.subCategory": `${req.body.selectedSubCategory}`,
        }
      };

if(req.body.selectedSize) {
  matchStage = {
      $match: {
         ...matchStage["$match"],
         "product.size": request.body.selectedSize
      }
  };
}

const searchResults = await user.aggregate([matchStage]);
```